# How do I reject/ignore an incoming call?

Tags: lumia, calls, lumia-635

Today I received a call from a number I didn't recognize.

I couldn't find a way to reject the the call so I was forced to let it ring.

The only option I was given was to swipe up, which I assumed would answer the call, which I didn't want to to.

I didn't find anything relevant when I looked it up. So how do I ignore/reject an incoming call on Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: Pressing the power button would stop the phone from ringing.

Comment: If you want to just stop it to make noise tap volume up or down once.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You do swipe up, then it presents 3 buttons, Answer, Ignore and Text Reply.

Answer (score 4):

Most Lumia phones should also support flip-to-silence (ignoring an incoming call by flipping the phone display down), which you can activate in Settings → Audio → Enhancements.

Microsoft's [Gestures Beta](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appId=38384829-0b39-4f21-a954-d2d4f8a4ac96) app also provides the same functionality, plus a few other handy features. Not sure if it'll work on your Lumia 635, though - Microsoft mentions that the 63x models have limited functionality, probably due to lacking a proximity sensor.

Comment: Note that not all phones (if any) need the Gestures app. In `settings > audio > enhancements` there is an option to "Flip to silence".

Comment: @Shawn You're completely right, I had forgotten about it. Will amend my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the Volume Button which would turn off the volume or even you can press the lock button which would turn off the volume as well as turn off screen(But it will not reject the call).